# Get the value of the checked item inside the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview defined as

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="gv1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" ReadOnly="true" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code is handled as

```
protected void gv1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
    {
       CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk1");
       if(check1 != null && check1.Checked)
       {
           label1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
       }
    }
}
```

The desired column is at index 1

However, the value is not obtained.

Comment: you're just grabbing every row and setting the value. I believe you want to grab the selectedrow

Comment: Cant you just reference this.chk1 and get the value from the codebehind?

Comment: You mean like this GridViewRow row = gv1.SelectedRow;   row.Cells[1].Text ?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly because code doesnt match with your words?

Comment: I am trying to display the data values inside the bound field when the corresponding check box is checked inside the grid view. It works using row.Cells[1].Text;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
label1.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need value not text. Do it like this

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below line may it help someone

```
var temp = ot_approval_grid.DataKeys[GridView.RowIndex].Value;
//ot_approval_grid is the id of grid view

foreach (GridViewRow GridView in ot_approval_grid.Rows)
{
    CheckBox isapplicable = (CheckBox)GridView.FindControl("chkrow");
    if (isapplicable != null && isapplicable.Checked)
    {
        //var temp = GridView.Cells["OTApplicationID"];
        var temp = ot_approval_grid.DataKeys[GridView.RowIndex].Value;
    }
}
```